# Delete foreign key when related entity is set to null on attached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have a DAO class that update an entity received from a client app. So I attach the entity to the context, but if a related entity is set to null in the client, after save the foreingn key is not set to null in the database,and then when I query entity, the related entity still there.

How I can delete foreing key in this case? (I can't examine each property manually, because the model is to big)

**EDIT:** It works fine when I query de entity in the dbcontext, the problem is when the entity is modified in the client and then attached to the dbcontext.

This is an example: when I set `person.Address.Neighborhood = null;` the **NeighborhoodId** property **still 7** in the int the **Address** table.

```
var person = new Person
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Juan",
    Adress = new Address
    {
        Id = 3,
        StreetName = "Calle Falsa",
        StreetNumber = "123",
        Neighborhood = new Neighborhood
        {
            Id = 7,
            Description = "my Neighborhood"
        },
    }
};

person.Address.Neighborhood = null; 

_context.Attach(person);
_context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
var unchange = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
if (unchange != null && unchange.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var unaEntidad in unchange )
    {
        _context.Entry(unaEntidad.Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT:** The classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string StreetName { get; set; }
    public virtual string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Neighborhood Neighborhood { get; set; }
}

public class Neighborhood
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so are you wanting to delete the relationship`only` or delete the `entity` and thus the relationship?

Comment: relationship only

Comment: can you edit your post to show classes for `Person` and `Neigbourhood`?

Comment: I already edited the question.

Comment: in `Person` add `public int AddressId { get; set; }`

Comment: add attribute `[ForeignKey("AddressId")] to the `Address` property

Comment: Why AddressId in Person?

Comment: because you have Address - this is a common pattern.  take a look at this page describing a blog from microsoft.  they use this pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is (could be a bug?) that `.State = EntityState.Modified;` does not mark the `null` reference navigation properties as modified (which otherwise it does for primitive and non null reference navigation properties).

The fix/workaround is to manually mark them as modified after setting the entity state with code like this:

```
foreach (var reference in _context.Entry(person).References)
    reference.IsModified = true;
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work.  It works fine when I query de entity from dbcontext and then set null the related entity and save changes. The problem is when the entity is modified in the client and then attached to the dbcontext and save changes

Comment: I always test before posting a solution and it worked for me. All I did was to take your code from the post (which apparently uses disconnected object) and add the above snippet right after `_context.Attach(person); context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;`. Then `SaveChages` generated `UPDATE` command with `null` for the FK.
`

Answer (score 0):

Person model should have a nullable address entity

```
public class Person {
  public Nullable<Address> Adress {get;set;}
}
```